# Can time(NULL) ever return failure?

Tags: c, time, posix

Can the `time_t time(time_t *t)` function ever return failure if the argument passed is always NULL?

If the call is `time(NULL)`, do we still need to check for the return value?

The only documented error code is EFAULT, which relates to the pointer being invalid.

Comment: @user3159253 It could return EFAULT in the case of `time((time_t*)junk)`, for some junk value. Although at the point of being able to return EFAULT, I'd already consider the programs behavior forfeit.

Comment: For *some* junk. The question seems moot, but .. meh, let the lawyers feed.

Comment: @user3159253 Nothing to do with being well known (although that made it a very practical choice among other implications); it could have been any value (**), had it been codified into the function contract.

Comment: For a given platform? No, for a given platform NULL pointer is determined completely. But sure, it could be != 0

Comment: Well, there's no EFAULT at all.


Neither in [Linux-specific time() implementation in GLIBC](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/time.c;h=a20efb43639d8ad81981a778e9f35a016265d555;hb=HEAD)  nor in FreeBSD [gettimeofday](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/lib/libc/sys/gettimeofday.c)

Comment: On some commercial \*NIX `time(NULL)` was crashing. Don't remember the details though. On the relevant project, the style was always `time(&timvar);` without any further error checking. On all modern *relevant* \*NIX-y systems `time(NULL)` doesn't fail. (What's more, on Linux and BSD the syscall is optimized such, that it can't even detect errors.) YMMV

Comment: depends on what's being tested. And the function after the outcome

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes. `time` has a documented *may fail* case:

> The time() function may fail if:
>
> [EOVERFLOW] The number of seconds since the Epoch will not fit in an object of type time_t.

Source: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/time.html

Expect this to happen in practice in about 22 years, no sooner, and not on 64-bit systems or 32-bit ones that utilize a 64-bit `time_t`.

Also, the presence of any *shall fail* or *may fail* cases also allows for implementation-defined errors, though their existence would be a serious quality-of-implementation flaw.

`EFAULT` is a non-issue/non-existent because it only happens when your program has undefined behavior.

So despite all this, in the real world, `time` is not actually going to fail.

Comment: That's fine for posix, but the specifics documented are not standard C.

Comment: @Peter: The question is tagged posix.

Comment: And C, R.  It is applicable to one but not the other.  Hence my comment.

Comment: "no sooner"...  if you assume the machine's clock is correct  ;)

Answer (score 5):

> Can time(NULL) ever return failure?

No. C standard says that

**C11: 7.27.2.4:**

> The time function returns the implementation’s best approximation to the current calendar time. The value `(time_t)(-1)` is returned if the calendar time is not available.

Comment: I guess `(time_t)(-1)` is in some sense a "best approximation" if time information cannot be retrieved... although it is debatable how useful this approximation is in practice if not treated as an error condition.

Answer (score 4):

I've checked on RHEL, SLES and UBTU; the [*man 2* page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/time) yields the same (relevant) thing:

> ```
>   time() returns the time since the Epoch (00:00:00 UTC, January 1, 1970), measured in seconds.
> ```

```
   If t is non-NULL, the return value is also stored in the memory pointed to by t.
```

Anyway, going back to the original questions

- *Q0*: *Can the `time_t time(time_t *t)` function ever return failure if the argument passed is always NULL?*

  - *A/R0*: **Yes**, if some very special events occurred (memory full, and so on, ...)
- *Q1*: *If the call is time(NULL), do we still need to check for the return value?*

  - *A/R1*: The actual answer is "NO", you don't have to; the fact that the func could return something relevant, is a different story. After all, why calling a func ,if there's no need of doing so?
- *Q2*: *The only documented error code is `EFAULT`, which relates to the pointer being invalid.*

  - You don't have anything to do with the invalid codes; as you said you're passing `NULL`, so there's no problem.

Answer (score 4):

In the C standard, `time()` can return `(time_t)(-1)` if "the calendar time is not available".  In the 1999 standard, for example, that is in Section 7.23.2.4, para 3.

Although that wording is less than specific, I would suggest it represents an error condition.   Presumably an implementation can return `(time_t)(-1)` if it can't access the system clock, can't sensibly interpret the data it gets, etc.

R's answer describes what is the case for the posix spec.

Comment: Long ago, on VMS, the system clock was in local time. Until much later, when the OS gained timezone support, time() always returned -1.

Answer (score 3):

(Not consider POSIX degraded mode functionality)

If the underlying real-time clock sub-system had a hardware fault like loss of clock integrity (battery) when the unit was off on an independent system, the return value of `time()` could certainly be `(time_t) -1`.  In that case, it make no difference what the passed in `time_t*` was.